# viewWithTag return nil, on subsequent calls to cellForRowAtIndexPath

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uitableview

I have a UITableView with a prototype table cell, I have a UIImageView a UILabel and 2 Buttons objects which inherit from UIButton on the cell with different tags (i.e. 100,200,300), I created this using IB. I use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier to get the cell in cellForRowAtIndexPath and it always returns a cell.

The first time cellForRowAtIndex path runs [cell viewWithTag:TAG] returns the correct object for each UI element, however on the second run (when I scroll a bit) all the objects are returned correctly except the two UIButton objects which are nil. (In the debugger their address is all zeros).

I have no idea what would cause this, as all my other table view work with similar code.

Update: If I make the type id for the Buttons in cellForRow they are not nil, but when I hover the object is shown as (UIButton *).  But if I have any code following [cell ViewWithTag:Button1Tag] that sends messages to the id object it become nil. Very Strange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I ended up using [GDB](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/debugging/debugging-with-gdb-introduction-to-commands.html) (Which is awesome) within XCode to look inside the Cell using [recursiveDescription](http://mobiledevelopertips.com/debugging/debugging-with-gdb-print-object-and-uiview-recursivedescription.html). It was showing that my tag had gone and then I realised I was setting the tag on cellForRow to hold the row, overwriting the original IB set tag.